# Linux swap memory more than available

Tags: linux, memory, rhel

I am confused when running free command in my RHEL machine, it shows irregular output

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           15G       9.5G       6.0G       1.2G       156M       4.2G
-/+ buffers/cache:       5.2G        10G
Swap:         2.0G       2.0G       297G
```

**Total** : 2.0G
**Used**  : 2.0G

Then how `free` is `297G`??

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `free` output is corrupted.

You can have a look at the raw data in `/proc/meminfo`. If this data is wrong too, it means the kernel can't count your memory correctly, and you should really worry.